# Function with numerical integrals, Plot3D works but NMaximize doesn't

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I have the following problem: I have a function `enter code here`H depending on two numerical integrals `g` and `d`, Mathematica is able to draw the 3D-Plot of the function `H`, but it isn't able to compute `NMaximize`.

I know that a common problem is the argument of a function, so I tried to be as precise as possible:

```
g[s_, eps_, tau_] := 
      NIntegrate[
      x^(s - 2) Exp[-x] (1 - Cos[x tau]) Coth[x/(2 eps)], {x, 0,
            Infinity}] 

d[s_, eps_, tau_] := 
     NIntegrate[
      x^(s - 1) Exp[-x]/
        2 (1 - Cos[tau x])/(1 - (Cosh[x/(2 eps )])^2), {x, 0, 
       Infinity}]


H[s_, eps_, tau_, d_, g_] := (2*(d)^2)/(Exp[2*g] - 1)
```

*Mathematica* doen't give me any problem with the `Plot3D` of `H`

```
With[{s = 1}, 
 Plot3D[H[s, eps, tau, d[s, eps,tau], 
   g[s, eps, tau]] , {eps, 1, 15}, {tau, 0.1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic ]]
```

But when I try to find which values of tau do maximize `H`, it says that `NIntegrate` has evaluated `g` to non-numerical values (`NIntegrate::inumr` message). Here's my code:

```
topt[eps_] := 
 With[{s = 1}, 
  NMaximize[ 
   H[s, eps, tau, d[s, eps, tau], 
    g[s, eps, tau]] , {tau} ∈ 
    Interval[{0.2, 1}] ] ]

topt[2]
```

I don't get why in the `Plot3D` there is no problem with the numeric integration while using `NMaximize` *Mathematica* isn't able to calculate it. I looked for errors in the syntax, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Look up the `Attributes` of `Plot3D` and `NMaximize`.  `Plot3D` is `HoldAll` and `NMaximize` is not.  The difference means that `H[..]` is evaluated before it is passed to `NMaximize`, at which point `tau` is a symbol, not a number. For `Plot3D`, evaluation is "held" (not done) and the code is passed to `Plot3D` as is; it is not evaluated until `eps` and `tau` have been assigned numeric values.

Comment: For me, `topt[2]` returns an answer (after a few minutes).  The messages, strictly speaking, are just warnings, not errors.

Comment: In particular, this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `_?NumericQ`  in function definiton.

```
g[s_?NumericQ, eps_?NumericQ, tau_?NumericQ] := 
   NIntegrate[
   x^(s - 2) Exp[-x] (1 - Cos[x tau]) Coth[x/(2 eps)], {x, 0,   Infinity}]

d[s_?NumericQ, eps_?NumericQ, tau_?NumericQ] := 
   NIntegrate[
   x^(s - 1) Exp[-x]/2 (1 - Cos[tau x])/(1 - (Cosh[x/(2 eps)])^2), {x, 
    0, Infinity}]


 H[s_?NumericQ, eps_?NumericQ, tau_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, 
    g_?NumericQ] := (2*(d)^2)/(Exp[2*g] - 1)

topt[eps_] := 
  With[{s = 1}, 
    NMaximize[{H[s, eps, tau, d[s, eps, tau], g[s, eps, tau]], .2 < 
      tau < 1}, tau]]

 topt[2]

(*   {1.15071, {tau -> 0.64901}}   *)
```